# Implementing unified types across multiple assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, binary-compatibility

I have a situation in which I'd like to implement the same type in multiple assemblies, but have them appear to the compiler to be the "same" type.

Why would I want to do this?  I am in the process of implementing some of my base class libraries in NuGet packages so I can more easily use them in new projects.  As these new projects may be, for example, WPF applications or UWP apps, some of these NuGet packages will have multiple assemblies in them targeted at different frameworks where appropriate.

Consider the following contrived scenario.  I have a NuGet package containing class library assemblies for .Net Framework 4.6, Windows 8.1, and UWP.  They all implement an `IExample` with exactly the same signature.  I then create a PCL targeting .Net Framework 4.5 and Windows 8 that includes this NuGet package and defines an `ExampleClass` that implements `IExample`.  Then, in a WPF application targeting .Net Framework 4.6, I include this same NuGet package and the PCL and instantiate `ExampleClass`.  I want to be able to test my instance of `ExampleClass` for compatibility with `IExample` even though the implementation of `ExampleClass` in the PCL uses a different declaration of `IExample` than the `IExample` used in the WPF application to test the class instance's type compatibility.

```
var myClass = new ExampleClass();
if (myClass is IExample)
{
    // class is an example, do something useful.
}
```

When I tried something like this in a simple test application, Visual Studio displayed a code smell on the `is` expression indicating that the test would never be true.  Even when I added the same GUID to all declarations of the interface the problem remained.

I presume this must be possible since it seems that Microsoft has done something similar in some of their NuGet packages.  For example, the description for the [Microsoft BCL Portability Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl) states:

> These types are "unified" to their later version equivalent. For example, when running on .NET Framework 4.5, IProgress from this package will be seen by the runtime as the same type as the one already available in the platform.

What more than a type's GUID is needed to cause multiple declarations of it to appear to be the same to the compiler?

Comment: Maybe they're using [binding redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions)?

Comment: I often use a Shared Project for the types I want to use in multiple assemblies.

Comment: Shared projects do not in of themselves produce assemblies.  Though they would be useful for sharing the definition of common code elements, they'd be compiled separately into each of the projects/assemblies that use the shared project and thus still be completely different types as far as the compiler is concerned.  Having tried this setup in my simple test application, I still get the code smell on the `is` expression indicating a "Suspicious type check: ..." because the interface on the class from the PCL is not the same as the interface in the main application used to do the type check.

Comment: Or maybe it implements an implicit operator?

Comment: @Biscuits, My understanding of binding redirection is that it indiscriminately sends all references for one assembly to another.  In the Microsoft example I cited, they imply that the types are "unified" on a case-by-case basis, and in my case I was hoping to be able to, for example, "unify" interfaces but not the classes that implement them.

Comment: @Biscuits, I believe implicit operators have to be defined on the types to be converted and are thus restricted to structs and classes.  The Microsoft example implies that the different declarations of their "unified" interface types can be used interchangeably on any type that implements them without requiring those types to be specially modified.  Implicit operators would be an option where the set of concrete types implementing an interface is known at design time, but I was hoping to find a more general solution in which interfaces be "unified" without reference to their implementations.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying. Please do share the answer when you discover it.

Comment: Maybe they're using [type forwarding](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Nov/23/NET-Standard-20-Making-Sense-of-NET-Again#Underthecovers)?